# VBA code to Insert a Column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to insert a column to the right if string"P018" is present in the third row of the sheet:

My code is :

```
Sub Insrt()
Dim Found As Range
Dim LR As Long
Dim I As Integer
I = 1
Do While Cells(4, I).Value <> ""
'If Cells(3, I).Value = "P018" Then
Set Found = Cells(3, I).Find(what:="P018", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
If Found Is Nothing Then GoTo Label
Found.Offset(, 1).EntireColumn.Insert

Label:
    Loop
End Sub
```

This going in an endless loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a standard for loop that loops backwards:

```
Sub insert()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim i As Long


Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
    lastColumn = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = lastColumn To 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(3, i) = "P018" Then Columns(i + 1).insert
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works but it is adding two columns after "P018" .... what if I want to insert the column U after every "P018" instead of blank columns...thnx

Comment: Are you sure you did not run it twice?  It should only add one, as that is all the code is telling it to do.  As far as adding the U column that is not in your scope of this question.  Please try to modify this code on your own, if you get stuck write a new question. @Shank

Comment: I just did:If .Cells(3, i) = "P018" Then Columns(i + 1).insert
       If .Cells(3, i) = "P018" Then Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(20).Copy

    If .Cells(3, i) = "P018" Then Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(i + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: That will work and good on you for doing it on your own, but you can make it prettier by making the IF statement into a multiline IF.  Research on IF Functions in vba.  There is a lot of tutorials on how to use it.